# No module named 'blog.slugs'

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to create a blog website.but when i try to import generate_unique_slug from .slugs django throws an error
**No module named 'blog.slugs'**. can you help me fix this?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from user_profile.models import User
from django.utils.text import slugify
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from .slugs import generate_unique_slug

# Create your models here.


class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        related_name='user_blogs',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    category = models.ForeignKey(
        Category,
        related_name='category_blogs',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

    title = models.CharField(
        max_length=250
    )
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True)
    banner = models.ImageField(upload_to='blog_banners')
    description = RichTextField()
    created_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        updating = self.pk is not None
        
        if updating:
            self.slug = generate_unique_slug(self, self.title, update=True)
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            self.slug = generate_unique_slug(self, self.title)
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *
# Register your models here.


admin.site.register(Category)
admin.site.register(Blog)
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'user_profile',
    'ckeditor',
]
```

when i delete this code `from .slugs import generate_unique_slug` the error disappears.maybe I'm importing it wrong?I will be very grateful if you help to solve the problem

Comment: So is there a file 'blog.slugs' ? What is inside?

Comment: @BartoszStasiak it does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line

```
from .slugs import generate_unique_slug
```

You are trying to import generate_unique_slug from you project file, and as you commented you don’t have this file in your project

The solution is you should write this function **generate_unique_slug** you can put it in file call **slugs.py** and it will work, or write this function inside model and delete this line

**Note:** this function should contain the logic for generate a unique slug depends on what you want